# Apache Tomcat websockets implementation on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websocket

I am trying to learn websockets. Tried a few examples given on apache tomcat 7 websockets examples -> 'http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html'. I'm done with the client-side code. having a problem with the server-side one which is to be written in a java servlet. I tried to run the examples on my localhost using eclipse and Apache Tomcat 7.0.52.
Can anyone help me with some tutorials and examples for the server code.

Here is the client side code for a simple echo server:

```
var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/"; 
var output; 

function init() { 
output = document.getElementById("output");
$('‪#‎send‬').click(function(){
doSend("ja ghari");
});
testWebSocket(); } 

function testWebSocket() {
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt);};
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) ;}; 
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) ;}; 
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) ;}; } 

function onOpen(evt) { 
writeToScreen("CONNECTED"); 
doSend("WebSocket rocks");
} 

function onClose(evt) { 
writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED"); } 

function onMessage(evt) { 
writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>'); 
} 

function onError(evt) { 
writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data); } 

function doSend(message) { 
writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
websocket.send(message); } 

function writeToScreen(message) { 
var pre = document.createElement("p"); pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
pre.innerHTML = message; output.appendChild(pre); } 

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

now i need to write a server side code in java for this
I need a server which will communicate with my client using websockets

Apache Tomcat 7 or above is a must, server side code to be written in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are more likely to get an answer if you say what language you want the server-side code in, and then tag the question appropriately

Comment: I need to write it in java, using a java servlet. sorry for not mentioning it

Answer (score 12):

Apache Tomcat 7 ships with an example WebSocket echo implementation.

- [Client side code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/archive/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml?view=annotate)
- [Server side code using annotations](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/archive/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/echo/EchoAnnotation.java?view=annotate)
- [Server side code without annotations](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/archive/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/echo/EchoEndpoint.java?view=annotate)

You don't write the server side as a Servlet. You need to implement a WebSocket endpoint. Tomcat will handle the plumbing to route the request to the endpoint.

Comment: Hey mark yeah i have the whole documentation of tomcat examples. I need to write a similar code for echo server. Can you guide me how do i get about it. I need a server which will communicate with my client using a websocket.

Comment: @Padfoot I have given you the source code for two different server implementations of an EchoServer. What else are you looking for?

Comment: yeah i tried those it gives me an error "Websocket connection closed error code 1006" everytime

Comment: @Padfoot I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @TheThom here is a tutorial which will help you http://playjava.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/websocket-in-java-part-1-before-java-ee7/

Comment: this is an old thread, but here to say those examples work perfectly fine.  if they didn't, they wouldn't have long since been shipping in the tomcat distro.

Comment: Links are expired